# Laravel 5.7 Testing with Passport in seeder

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.7, laravel-passport, laravel-seeding, laravel-testing

I have a UsersTableSeeder which generates a Passport personal token:

```
$user = factory(User::class)->create([
    'email' => 'someone@example.com',
]);

Artisan::call('passport:client', [
    '--personal' => 'default',
    '--no-interaction' => true,
]);
```

However, when I seed my tests with `$this->artisan('db:seed');`, I'm receiving the following error:

> Mockery\Exception\BadMethodCallException: Received Mockery_1_Illuminate_Console_OutputStyle::askQuestion(), but no expectations were specified

Comment: What happens when you run the seeders from your console, e.g. `php artisan db:seed`?

Comment: @DelenaMalan It runs correctly.

Comment: Where are you running `$this->artisan('db:seed')`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `passport:client` command is failing because even with `--no-interaction` flag it asks for the client's name if not provided. And the test doesn't know what to answer so it fails.

The following works for me.

`Artisan::call('passport:client --name=<client-name> --no-interaction --personal');`

Hope it helps!